# Links to a Hangout session

Tags: web, google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

On a website I would like to have a link which directs all users to the same Google Hangout session. How could this be done?

Comment: This is somehow related to my question. I started a hangout on my phone, but I'm unable to find/access it from a desktop browser: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24032/access-old-google-hangout-from-web-browser

Answer (score 1):

Use a [named hangout](http://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1666009&rd=1).

When starting a hangout, click "Hangouts with extras" and name the hangout.  Then you can use the public link generated with your hangout name to link to the hangout.